# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in a form being sent to an api

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to test whether my shipping form information is being sent correctly to shippos api, but I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')` (ShippingAddress.js:24 -> `value ={form.name}`). For some reason, all of my `value={form.''}` elements are giving me this result, and I'm unsure why this is happening. I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

ShippingAddress.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


export const ShippingForm = props => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState(props.form)
  
    const submit = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      fetch('https://api.goshippo.com/addresses/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ form }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'ShippoToken process.env.SHIPPO_TOKEN'},
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => setForm(json.form))
    }
  

    return (
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="form[name]"
          value={form.name}
          onChange={e => setForm({ ...form, name: e.target.value })}
        />
        {form.errors.name && <p>{form.errors.name}</p>}
        <input
        type="text"
        name="form[street1]"
        value={form.street1}
        onChange={e => setForm({ ...form, street1: e.target.value })}
        required
        />
        {form.errors.name && <p>{form.errors.name}</p>}
         ...
        <input type="submit" name="Shipping Form" />
      </form>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying Cannot read properties of undefined, and in this case, it's saying form is undefined.

You should console log props.form and see what you're getting. It could be that there's some problem in the component which is passing the form.
Or maybe you have to do useState({...props.form}), I'm not sure.